# The number of ways to choose additional courses

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose some university offers 7 additional yearly courses for students. Each course is read every year and a student can take any number of those courses in any year of his/her studies. Assume students do not repeat courses.

In how many ways can a student choose additional courses? ( The answer 5040 is incorrect)

Comment: 5040 is 7!, the number of different orderings of seven courses. To either select or not select 7 courses can be thought of as a binary number with 7 bits. This leads to 128 different selections.

Comment: @AxelKemper  You should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each additional course doubles the number of choices because you can either select it or not. For one course, there are two choices. For two courses, you get four. This inductive argument leads to 128 choices for seven courses.